# how to read math symbols

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to write a program in which a user inputs the character of a math operation, for example; + or - .

It will be used on 2 other numbers and finally show the result.

My char is OP and i tried using

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
   float innum;
System.out.println("Please input 2 Numbers");
for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
    innum=in.nextFloat();
}
System.out.println("please input an operation symbol");
char OP=in.next().charAt(0);
if ( OP=="+"){
```

but it shows an error.

Comment: Can you show your code and the error message please??? This bit of information you have so far is pretty much useless..

Comment: float innum;
System.out.println("Please input 2 Numbers");
for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
 innum=in.nextFloat();
}
System.out.println("please input an operation symbol");
char OP=in.next().charAt(0);
if ( OP=="+"){

Comment: Ok, with the code provided for one, you cannot use equal operators the way you are. Equality operators only compare numbers...

Comment: what can I do sorry i am new to this

Comment: `if (Character.toString(OP).matches("+")) {
    // ...
}`

Comment: what is the { // ...} part for

Comment: Thats for whatever you decide to do if there is a match...

Comment: so     character.tostring(OP).matches("+")  is what checks the char

Comment: Than you very much i now have a clear idea on how to continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also think if you had defined it as a character it might simply your work. where you defined

```
float innum;
char plus ='+';
char minus = '+';
char times = 'x';
```

...
and then you use

```
`if (Character.toString(OP).matches(plus)) { // ... }
```

this will make your work more granular.